# How to remove an item from a StringSet in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have this table in DynamoDB:

```
{
  "lectures": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "lecture_id": {
            "S": "CC0"
          },
          "students": {
            "SS": [
              "",
              "test"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove `"test"` from the StringSet `students`.

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.DELETE), I tried this code:

```
function removeLecture(event){
    const students = 'lectures[' + Number.parseInt(event.lecture_id) + '].students';
    console.log('test: ' + students);
    const params = {
        TableName: 'TableName',
        Key: {
            'Key': key
        },
        UpdateExpression: `DELETE ${students} :student`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':student' : {
                'SS': event.student
            }
        },
        ReturnValues : 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }
    
    return ddb.update(params).promise();
}
```

Anyway, I receive a `ValidationException`:

```
START RequestId: 3857a2c2-23a8-4c0c-b080-516669c6e615 Version: $LATEST
2021-08-18T10:21:39.078Z    3857a2c2-23a8-4c0c-b080-516669c6e615    INFO    test: lectures[0].students
2021-08-18T10:21:39.831Z    3857a2c2-23a8-4c0c-b080-516669c6e615    INFO    ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: DELETE, operand type: MAP, typeSet: ALLOWED_FOR_DELETE_OPERAND
```

I have also tried with `ExpressionAttributeValues: {':student' : event.student}`, but still I receive the same error with `STRING` instead of `MAP`.

How can I remove the String from the StringSet?

Comment: Gonna post this as a comment since it's just a wild guess.. could it be that lecturs[n].students does not exist in the item you're updating? I believe DELETE will only work if the value actually exists, and is a string set.

Comment: @AugustLilleaas as you can see by the output of the log, I'm testing lectures[0], which actually exists. Moreover the error says "incorrect operand type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long trying, I discovered the function `createSet()` of the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` class. I tried to use it, and it works. So the answer is: **if you want to remove a String from a StringSet, you have to create another StringSet and remove the latter from the original**.

Here is the code:

```
function removeLecture(event){
    const students = 'lectures[' + Number.parseInt(event.lecture_id) + '].students';
    console.log('test: ' + students);
    const params = {
        TableName: 'TableName',
        Key: {
            'Key': key
        },
        UpdateExpression: `DELETE ${students} :student`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':student' : ddb.createSet(event.student)
        },
        ReturnValues : 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }
    
    return ddb.update(params).promise();
}
```